# Swagger API structure for POST request without body parameters

Tags: react-native, express, swagger

POST request without body parameter gives a JSON parse error. Mentioned the error below.

API Call

```js
api.post('notification/seen')
```

Error:

> {"message":{"name":"SyntaxError","msg":"Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0","stack":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse ()\n    at createStrictSyntaxError (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)\n    at parse (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)\n    at /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18\n    at invokeCallback (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)\n    at done (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)\n    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)"},"level":"error","timestamp":"2021-09-28T06:29:19.577Z"}

Swagger API structure

```yaml
    /notification/seen:
        post:
          tags:
            - Notification
          responses:
            204:
              description: Update Seen Notification Success
            401:
              description: Access Token Missing/Expired
            500:
              description: Something went wrong!
```

If same API I call with adding dummy body as below with changing the Swagger API structure I am not getting the error.

API Call

```js
api.post('notification/seen',{id:"data"})
```

Swagger API structure

```yaml
    /notification/seen:
        post:
          tags:
            - Notification
          parameters:
            - in: body
              name: body
              schema:
                type: object
          responses:
            204:
              description: Update Seen Notification Success
            401:
              description: Access Token Missing/Expired
            500:
              description: Something went wrong!
```

And also if I change POST to GET request then also I am not getting the error.

How to fix the error with the POST request without a body parameter?

Comment: Should `api.psot` be `api.post`?